# How to provide access of action methods for particular user in a controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here, suppose we have two users User1 and User2, and
there are two action methods in controller,

```
  public class HomeController:Controller
   {

     public ActionResult Method1()
     {
       return View();
     }

     public ActionResult Method2()
     {
       return View();
     }
   }
```

For the user1, i want to provide access both the methods, and for the user2, i want to provide access method1 only.

How it is Possible in MVC? Please help me anyone?

Comment: Consider sssigning roles to your users and apply the AuthoriseAttribute (e.g. [Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")] allows only users who are Administrators)

Comment: How to get user is Admin or User, suppose we provide [Authorize(User=username)], here how to get username?

Comment: You can't use a variable. Attributes can use only constant values so it has to be `[Authorize(Users="User1,User2")]` as Neel indicated.

Comment: But How to Know , particular user login is "User1" or "User2"??

Comment: See Neel's answer. `Method1()` has no Authorise attribute, so anyone can access it. `Method2()` has `[Authorize(Users="User1")]` so only the user whose login name is User1 can access it (User2 or any other user will get a 401 Access Denied error)

Comment: Ok, How could the method know login name is user1??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57375/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-chandu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Authorize` attribute and can decorate your code as below :-

```
public class HomeController:Controller
   {

     public ActionResult Method1()
     {
       return View();
     }

     [Authorize(Users="user1")]
     public ActionResult Method2()
     {
       return View();
     }
   }
```

For more details :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

Comment: Can I set Method2 for multiple users, suppose another user say "user3" want to provide access method2() can i set [Authorize(Users="user1,user3,...")], like this??

Comment: yes you can do it..go through the link where you will find in example they have done like [Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")] @Chandu

Comment: last one doubt, How to get "user1" is Alice or Bob, suppose i declare with string username="Alice", can i provide like [Authorize(User=username")

Comment: just wonder can i put directly list of users in users property dynamically ? or i have to go for custom authorization to do that ?

Comment: @Chandu and Vishal have a look here may be u get ur ans here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-vb